Keras: not sure why input shape in inception here is not working for image size and weights
inception = InceptionV3(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + [3], weights='imagenet', include_top = False)


Tried that and got this result:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2492d9d5dbf7> in <cell line: 4>()
2 #Will be using imagenet weights
3
----> 4 inception = InceptionV3(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + [3], weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/applications/imagenet_utils.py in obtain_input_shape(input_shape, default_size, min_size, data_format, require_flatten, weights)
377             if input_shape is not None:
378                 if len(input_shape) != 3:
--> 379                     raise ValueError(
380                         "input_shape must be a tuple of three integers."
381                     )
ValueError: input_shape must be a tuple of three integers.
Wondering if theres any update related to this as well, thank you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You should specify what IMAGE_SIZE  is. If you consider it as a list of two integers, it works fine. Also, you should indicates the precise modules that you are using. From my experience, this is my code:
import tensorflow.keras.applications as tfa

IMAGE_SIZE = [256, 256]
inception = tfa.InceptionV3(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + [3], weights='imagenet', include_top = False)

